# Concerning homology groups of the universal covering space of a finite polyhedron

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces, polyhedra

Suppose that $P$ is a finite polyhedron. I know that $H_i (\tilde{P})$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (P)]$-module for all $i$.

My question is that:
If $\pi_1 (P)$ is a free group, then is $H_i (\tilde{P})$ a projective $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (P)]$-module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $P$ to be the suspension of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$ (which I am not sure counts as a finite polyhedron for you), then $\pi_1(P)$ is the trivial free group, but $H_2(\tilde P)=H_2(P)=H_1(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: @ Kyle Miller Thank you for your interesting answer. I don't know that the suspension of a finite polyhedron is a finite polyhedron.

Comment: @M.Mohareri It certainly has a finite simplicial structure, and there was one reference I found which even let a "finite polyhedron" mean "finite CW complex."  The point of this possible example is if you find a simply connected finite polyhedron with torsion in the higher homology classes, then it would be a counterexample. I believe there are simply connected 5-manifolds with torsion in $H_2$ (2.1 at http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/5-manifolds:_1-connected ).

Comment: @ Kyle Miller Yes that's true. Thank you for your exact explanation. That's right. That manifold actually is the second counterexample for my question. Thank you so much for your help.